# Feature State Updating Automatically

Tags: azure-devops, state, activity-lifecycle

Feature cycle time is a very important metric, but in ADO there doesn't seem to be a way to get the State of a Feature to automatically update when the first story moves into Active (or the last child is closed). Does anyone know of a way to have this happen?

Answer (score 1):

No, that will never happen. This area for custom application and solutions. You can try the following:

1. [TFS Aggregator](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=tfsaggregatorteam.tfs-aggregator-server-plugin)
2. Write your own solution through rest api: [Automation of state changing for Azure DevOps work items based on states of child work items](https://oshamrai.wordpress.com/2019/02/19/automation-of-state-changing-for-azure-devops-work-items-based-on-states-of-child-work-items/)
3. Use additional solutions: [Automation of state changing with Azure Logic App](https://oshamrai.wordpress.com/2020/01/08/automated-state-changing-with-azure-logic-app-of-parent-work-items-if-child-work-items-were-changed-on-azure-devops/)